# Retrieve healthcheck info if Spring couldn't load context

Tags: spring

I have several beans in my context. Those beans take data from text files. 
If text file was not found bean would not be loaded.
If file format is wrong bean would not be loaded.

Other beans depend on those beans and so if any of them couldn't be loaded context can not be constructed.

Is there a way to get a list of beans, which weren't constructed?

What I want to do is to have a healthcheck page, which serves json over http to find which files couldn't be loaded and why. I'm using external framework to serve http and I'm accessing spring context through static variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have finally done is split the context in two. Something like that.

```
@Component
public class GoodBean{
    public Sting getStatus(){
        return "bad";
    }
}

@Component
public class ActionBean{
    public ActionBean(GoodBean goodBean) {
        if ("bad".equals(goodBean.getStatus()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("you can't make bad bean good");
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
public class GoodConfig {}


@Configuration
@Import(GoodConfig.class)
public class BadConfig {}
```

BadConfig imports GoodConfig. I can use GoodConfig to show that GoodBean status is bad. And I can use ActionBean config for everything else. And if everything else doesn't work, I can go to http endpoint and find out, whether it's because GoodBean has gone bad.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of failing those beans, you can collect errors (caught exceptions).

Then wire these beans to your health-checker, and retrieve all the errors.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing now.  The problem is that those beans provide data for other beans and other beans can not be constructed without them. And because other beans can not be constructed - the whole context can not be constructed. So I can't wire beans to healthchecker because I have no context.